# How to make JS via webkit work the same as via chromedriver?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webkit, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

There's a JS code which works fine via chromedriver but does not work via webkit.

I've found that the following JS not work via webkit because of the object's keys which contain numbers

```
  var contactData = $selectedContact[0].dataset;
  # contactData object structure
  # {descriptionLine-1: "",descriptionLine-2: "", name: "", phone: ""}
```

However, it works fine in chromedriver.

Configs I've tried:

```rb
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit # the code above does not work with webkit
```

```rb
  # rails_helper.rb
  require "selenium/webdriver"

  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[no-sandbox headless disable-dev-shm-usage])

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

How can I make the JS where object keys contain numbers work with webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "via webkit" you mean using the `capybara-webkit`- https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit - driver with Capybara, then the answer is that most likely you can't. The `capybara-webkit` driver was based on QtWebkit which stopped being developed years ago. The last stable version of QtWebkit released is basically equivalent to Safari from 7-8 years ago, so it doesn't support a lot of newer JS/CSS. There are some missing things you can polyfill, and you can make sure all your JS is transpiled to ES5 but it's still not going to 100% replicate a modern browser. That combined with the fact the `capybara-webkit` project is deprecated and will be archived in the next few weeks means it's time to move onto newer drivers.

Since you're already using headless chrome via selenium can't you just move all your tests to it? If not because you need whitelist/blacklist or other `capybara-webkit` extensions then you should be looking at one of the newer CDP based drivers like [Apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) although they're still in alpha/beta stability at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Thomas!

Comment: Btw, I don't use headless chrome because we use TravisCI, it's extremely slow in there